# How can I put same color (maroon) on the column A1x like F1x?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] 

\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0,0.87,0.68,0.32}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   
    \hline
   \rowcolor[gray]{.8}    & $A_{1x}$ & $A_{1y}$ & $A_{1z}$ & ... & $A_{19x}$ & $A_{19y}$ & $A_{19z}$\\\hline
   \rowcolor{maroon!40}    $F_{1x}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\\hline
    $F_{1y}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
    $F_{1z}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\\hline
    \vdots &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\\hline
  $F_{19x}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\\hline
     $F_{19y}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\\hline
     $F_{19z}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i still have a problem to insert my code in proper way :-|

Comment: You simply have to use the `{}` icon in the edit window toolbar.

Comment: Add  `\cellcolor{maroon}` before `A_{1x}` to neutralise the  `\rowcolor{gray}` command for this particular cell.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using color I have removed verticals/ horizontals -- you could put them back

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] 

\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0,0.87,0.68,0.32}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{maroon!40}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{gray!40}}c}


    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{bacccccc}
   
    \hline
   \rowcolor[gray]{.8}    & \cellcolor{maroon!40}$A_{1x}$ & $A_{1y}$ & $A_{1z}$ & ... 
   & $A_{19x}$ & $A_{19y}$ & $A_{19z}$\\\hline
   \rowcolor{maroon!40}    $F_{1x}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
    $F_{1y}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    $F_{1z}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
    \vdots &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
  $F_{19x}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
     $F_{19y}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
     $F_{19z}$ &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```